# Is there a way to see words looked up in Wikipedia?

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite

Kindle adds words you have looked up for which it can find a definition to the Vocabulary Builder, but it does not appear to save the words for which it can only find Wikipedia definitions. Is there a way to see all the words you have searched on Wikipedia?

I looked up this great word for a falcon that I'd never heard the other day, wasn't in the default dictionary. Now I have no idea what it was and I don't remember which book it was in.